# How to create expandable category in code activity using C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Activities;
using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace ClassMathCustomActivity
{
    public class SimpleFormula : CodeActivity
    {
        [Category("Input")]
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<double> FirstNumber { get; set; }

        [Category("Input")]
        public InArgument<double> SecondNumber { get; set; }

        [Category("Output")]
        public OutArgument<double> ResultNumber { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var firstNumber = FirstNumber.Get(context);
            var secondNumber = SecondNumber.Get(context);
            var result = System.Math.Pow(firstNumber + secondNumber, 2);
            ResultNumber.Set(context, result);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create sub category which can be expandable. Here we have "Appearance" category which have lot of properties like BackColor Text and font. My question is how to add expandable property in a category like font.
[Properties for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3g23.png).

Comment: Or I can say how to add expandable InArgument property in  Input category in above example?

Answer (score 0):

What about an object as the category:

```
// custom defined:
public class Appearance
{
    public Color color;
    public Font font;
    // ...
}

// or defined by inheritance:
public class Appearance : Button
{
    // ...
}

[Category("Input")]
public InArgument<Appearance> appearance { get; set; }
```

I created an `Appearance` class that contains the properties. You might want to inherit from `Button` class to have the same properties or define your own subset. Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
But this is not working for me. I have created Eligibility property of type EligibilityDenialProcess class which have multiple properties username, password etc.

```
    Category("Input1")]
    [Description("Environment like Production or QA (Test)")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<EligibilityDenialProcess> Eligibility { get; set; }
```

And output is not coming like expandable property. I am expecting In Input1  have one property Eligibility which can be expandable. Once i will expend(While cliking on + sign). I should able to provide InArguments UserName and Password details.

[Output what I am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjsZU.png)